# Raspberry Pi camera writing permissions

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

When writing a python script to take a picture every minute on the Pi, it spits out this error :

"mmal: main: Error opening output file:"

Python code:

```
jpeg_list = open('jpeg_still_list.txt','w')
count = 0
tlcount = 0
while True:
    os.system("raspistill -w 1920 -h 1080 -q 80 -o frames/%s.jpg" % count)
    jpeg_list.write("frames%s.jpg" % count)
    time.sleep(60)
    count = count+1

    if count == 180:
        count = 0

        os.system("mencoder -nosound -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:aspect=16/9:vbitrate=8000000 -vf scale=1920:1080 -o %s -mf type=jpeg:fps=24 mf://@jpeg_still_list.txt" %"lol")
```

I have googled the problem extensively, I came across this other stack overflow answer, which may be what i need to do.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/how-to-write-raspistill-image-to-usb-drive

But I think the file they are changing has changed format, because its not quite clear how to do that.

I have tried runnign it using sudo and superuser.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should use the subprocess module

Comment: That looks like a good idea,

Comment: Is frames a directory ?

Comment: Frames isnt a directory.

Comment: Then `frames/` is going to be the problem

Comment: there is what appears to be an inconsistency between `frames/%s.jpg` and `frames%s.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the subprocess module, in particular [check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
with open('jpeg_still_list.txt', 'w') as jpeg_list:
    from subprocess import check_call  
    count = 0
    tlcount = 0
    while True:
        check_call(["raspistill", "-w", "1920", "-h",
                    "1080", "-q", "80", "-o", "frames{}.jpg".format(count)])
        jpeg_list.write("frames{}.jpg".format(count))
        time.sleep(60)
        count += 1
        if count == 180:
            count = 0
        check_call(["mencoder", "-nosound", "-ovc", "lavc", "-lavcopts",
                    "vcodec=mpeg4:aspect=16/9:vbitrate=8000000", "-vf",
                    "scale=1920:1080", "-o", "lol", "-mf",
                    "type=jpeg:fps=24", "mf://@jpeg_still_list.txt"])
```

`frames/` means you want to open the .jpg file in the frames directory which does not exist so you get the error, remove the `/`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! this has certainly tidied up my code, but unfortunately I get the same error message!

Comment: @JonathanAbrahams, try removing the `/` as above.